# PHP How to order an array in ABC Order from a value of 1 of it's bounds

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array

Ok, I have an array like so:

```
$my_array = array(
    'hi' => array('description' => 'how are you?', 'title' => 'Hello', 'link' => 'http://mylink.com'),
    'bye' => array('description' => array('Goodbye!', 'see ya'), 'title' => 'See Ya Later', 'link' => 'http://mybyelink.com'),
    'not_now' => array('description' => array('I am away now!', 'gone'), 'title' => 'Away', 'link' => 'http://myawaylink.com'),
    'back' => array('description' => array('I am back now!', 'back', 'present'), 'title' => 'Here', 'link' => 'http://mybacklink.com'),
);
```

So I would like the array to be ordered, within php code, somehow so that it orders it by the TITLE of each array bound:  `$my_array['hi']['title']`, `$my_array['bye']['title']`, `$my_array['not_now']['title']`, and `$my_array['back']['title']`, but it MUST keep the array intact so that all of the values within the hi, bye, not_now, and back are the exact same and all of the arrays (if any are in it, are also the same).

So this array will need to be ordered in ABC order depending on the **title**, so should return in this order:

```
$my_array = array(
    'not_now' => array('description' => array('I am away now!', 'gone'), 'title' => 'Away', 'link' => 'http://myawaylink.com'),
    'hi' => array('description' => 'how are you?', 'title' => 'Hello', 'link' => 'http://mylink.com'),
    'back' => array('description' => array('I am back now!', 'back', 'present'), 'title' => 'Here', 'link' => 'http://mybacklink.com'),
    'bye' => array('description' => array('Goodbye!', 'see ya'), 'title' => 'See Ya Later', 'link' => 'http://mybyelink.com'),
);
```

Titles are in ABC order here:  Away, Hello, Here, and See Ya Later.

How can I do this and still keep the array intact with all of the sub-arrays in it also?

Thanks guys :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the uasort function with a user-defined sort function using strnatcmp in the function. Here is an example for your code:

```
function titleSort($a, $b) {
    return strnatcmp($a['title'], $b['title']);
}

uasort($my_array, 'titleSort');
```

If desired you could add some sanity checking on the input variables to make sure they are arrays by using is_array.

Comment: Wow, thanks a million, just what I needed here!  I don't understand why $a['title'] and $b['title'] are exactly the same, but than again, not familiar with the `uasort` function of PHP.  What does $a and $b represent exactly?  The different bounds of the arrays??

Comment: $a and $b represent two items of your array that you are comparing. So PHP iterates over your given array, in this case $my_array and it compares each array element with every other. So $a is an element of your $my_array and $b is another element of that array that it is comparing against. Your $my_array is multidimensional so therefore $a is also an array and one of the keys is 'title', same with $b. We could have compared anything in that sub-array. Of course, this assumes that every element of $my_array is formed the same way, i.e., is an array with a key of 'title'.